# Chapman Pugh Solutions

Tags: real-analysis, self-learning

I am currently teaching myself Real Analysis with Chapman Pugh's wonderful book and I am trying to solve every exercise. However, it would be nice to have the solutions to at least a number of the problems so see if I am at least solving them in somewhat of the right manner.

Also, would anyone happen to know if skipping the starred sections (Cantor Set lore etc) affect the read much?

Thanks!